# Do some tasks after OnAppearing() in MAUI

Tags: maps, maui, expander, maui-community-toolkit

I have a maui community toolkit expander control in my page. On Tapping the header the content is shown/hidden. I got a Maui map in the expander's content. It display properly if the expander is in 'Expanded' state. But if the page is loaded with 'Collapsed' State the map won't be displayed properly.

So I would like to keep the expander expanded once loading and after the `OnAppearing` I would like to keep it closed.

Is there any way I can call a method to change the state (`IsExpanded` to false) after the `OnAppearing`

```xml
<Page
  …
  xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
  xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps">

    <toolkit:Expander x:Name="expander" 
                      IsExpanded="True" 
                      ExpandedChanged="Expander_ExpandedChanged">
        <toolkit:Expander.Header>
            <Label Text="Show/Hide "
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   FontSize="Medium" />
        </toolkit:Expander.Header>
        <toolkit:Expander.Content>
            <StackLayout Margin="0"
                         Orientation="Horizontal">
                <maps:Map x:Name="map" 
                          HeightRequest="300" 
                          IsShowingUser="True" 
                          MapType="Satellite"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </toolkit:Expander.Content>
    </toolkit:Expander>
```

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can call a method to change the state (IsExpanded
> to false) after the OnAppearing?

Lifecycle functions that are triggered after a page is fully loaded are not yet included in MAUI.

But you can use the VisualElement.Loaded Event, it occurs when a VisualElement has been constructed and added to the object tree. This event may occur before the VisualElement has been measured so should not be relied on for size information.

```
YouControl.Loaded += (s, e) => {        };
```

Here is the information about [VisualElement.Loaded Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.visualelement.loaded?view=net-maui-7.0).